# Flutter: I Need help on a particular implementation with Navigator

Tags: flutter

I am on a particular situation I need to solve in the most performance way possible. Let me explain with an image:

[image]

- So, I have my entry point screen, a StatelessWidget with a bottomNavigationBar and 3 items (1,2,3)
- Item 2 is the default item.
- I need to press on item 3 and then push screens all the way to screen "C"
- At this point I need to return to entry point screen, (without popping all the way down if it is possible)
- Then activate item 1 (currently is 3)
- And funally push a new screen (E) from item 1

I am currently doing this by

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(Routes.home));
```

where Routes.home is my entry point, and with some streams I am managing the selection of item 1 and pushing screen E.
Now, this is working but I don't think is the best way to do this.
Neither I want to replace screen everytime I push a newone, for example, from A to B to C, I need those screens to be on the stack until I reach the lastone...

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Navigator` does not have the notion of storing screens on the stack in advance. If you really insist on the behavior where the user would go back to a screen they never were in, one way to do that is to simulate the back button on AppBar to do `Navigator.pushReplacement`, essentially providing your own Back button as `leading` widget.

Comment: If Navigator does not have the notion of storing screens so how I can do popUntil? Dont know what you mean with "in advance"...
Anyway, "go back to a screen they never were in" isn't true, like I say, what I want to do is going back from screen C to entry point screen, wich like you would assume, the user was there in the first place. THEN, but only then, I want to push a new Screen (E) from the entry point. 
Another question is: Why do I got downvoted on this question?